# Check if a type is/convertible to a range in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I want to write a function `print(std::ranges::range auto&& range)` which prints a range to `std::out`. This should be able to print a nested range recursively. I am new to this and still learning stuff. Here is a look at what I am expecting.

```cpp
void print(ranges::range auto &&range)
{
    if (std::is_convertible_v<ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>,ranges::range auto>)
    // or if constexpr(...) or std::is_same_v ???
    {
        for (auto &&subrange : range)
        {
            std::cout << "{\n";
            print(subrange);
            std::cout << "}\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "{";
        for (auto &&i : range)
        {
            std::cout << i << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work. I want to know how to do the comparison that some type can be a range? Any help is appreciated. Alternate approaches are welcome.

In gcc12 this results in

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
[build]    90 |     if (std::is_convertible_v<ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>,ranges::range auto>)
[build]       |         ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] 0x7f11b04f8cef ???
[build]     ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
[build] 0x7f11b04e050f __libc_start_call_main
[build]     ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
[build] 0x7f11b04e05c8 __libc_start_main_impl
[build]     ../csu/libc-start.c:381
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine whether it is a nested range by detecting whether the reference type (or value type) of the range also models the `range` concept, for example

```
void print(ranges::range auto&& range)
{
    // nested range
    if constexpr (ranges::range<ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>>) {
      // ...
    }
    else {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Note that `if constexp` must be used to avoid hard errors for instantiation of branches that do not satisfy constraints. And it may also need to check whether the element type is printable through other concepts.

Comment: This works. Is the segfault in gcc12 a possible compiler bug?

Comment: @ArnabMahanti Yes, although your attempt is ill-formed, the internal compiler error always indicates that this is a compiler error.